# Create a view having detailed information from a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection with the records as below. Here one document has all the details for a person. A person can have the contact information of types - Email, phone and physical or home address. for each of those fields, more than one value can be specified or the field can be left blank. It is also possible that no value is provided for some fields and in that case, the collection will not have any value.

```
[
  {
    id: 'objectId1',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactInfo: {
      Email: [
        'first@email',
        'second@email'
      ],
      phone: [
        123456
      ],
      homeAddress: [
        'address1'
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'objectId2',
    name: 'Name2',
    contactInfo: {
      Email: [
        'name2@email'
      ],
      homeAddress: [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'objectId3',
    name: 'Name3',
    contactInfo: {
      
    }
  }
]
```

and I want to have the details in flat format , for example taking the above mongo collection record as an example, the details will look like the below

```
[
  {
    id: 'newObjectId1',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactType: 'Email',
    contactInfo: 'first@email'
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId2',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactType: 'Email',
    contactInfo: 'second@email'
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId3',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactType: 'phone',
    contactInfo: '123456'
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId4',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactType: 'homeAddress',
    contactInfo: 'address1'
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId5',
    name: 'Name2',
    contactType: 'Email',
    contactInfo: 'name2@email'
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId6',
    name: 'Name2',
    contactType: 'homeAddress',
    contactInfo: null
  },
  {
    id: 'newObjectId7',
    name: 'Name3'
  }
]
```

How do I go about writing the query to create the view?